# Unable to save in the database

Tags: php, joomla1.5

My problem was I was not able to save the data in the database, here is the part of the code

```
$database =& JFactory::getDBO();
$sql = "UPDATE #__comp_rate SET total = total + 1, point = point + $rate_d WHERE store='".intval($_GET['id'])."'";
echo $sql;
$database->setQuery($sql);
```

the the result of the echo is:

```
" point = point + 4 WHERE store='170'4"
```

it should be:

```
"UPDATE jos_com_rate SET total = total + 1, point = point + 4 WHERE store='170'"
```

Comment: Still doesn't fix the issue.. this is kinda weird..

Comment: Can you `echo $_GET['id']` and share the result?

Comment: What is `#__comp_rate`? A constant?

Comment: echo  `intval($_GET['id'])` before query run and see what is the result

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://codepad.viper-7.com/aRpqiA). The described behaviour is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big fan on how joomla handles a lot of things, but they implement their query objects a bit like Zend used to do. I dont think Joomla is very good with direct SQL anyway so better use their build in query builder :

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
// Fields to update.
$fields = array(
    $db->quoteName('total') . ' =  ' . $db->quoteName('total') . '+1' ,
    $db->quoteName('point') . ' =  ' . $db->quoteName('point') . '+' . $db->quote($rate_d) ,
);
// Conditions for which records should be updated.
$conditions = array(
    $db->quoteName('store') . ' = ' . $db->quote($_GET['id']),
);
$query->update($db->quoteName('#__comp_rate'))->set($fields)->where($conditions);
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->query();
```